# Font embedding for component classes

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, text, fonts, flash-cs5

Firstly, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569845/actionscript-3-font-embedding) thoroughly, and none of the answers help.

I am working on a component class, that will allow the developer to set the label and font of the label in the Flash CS5 IDE. The problem I'm having is that when I try to use the `TextFormat` class to set the font and size etc. It doesn't appear. If I remove `embedFonts = true` then it doesn't use the format at all and just prints my text in the `Times New Roman` font instead. Here is my code:

```
frmt = new TextFormat();
frmt.font = FontName;
frmt.size = labelSize;
frmt.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
label_txt = new TextField();
label_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
label_txt.embedFonts = true;
//label_txt.selectable = false;
label_txt.defaultTextFormat = frmt;
label_txt.setTextFormat(frmt);
label_txt.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, textDrawHandler);
addChild(label_txt);
```

and then in the enterFrame event:

```
label_txt.text = label;
label_txt.setTextFormat(this.frmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fonts disappear when `embedFonts` is true, then you either:

- have not [embedded the correct font subset](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html)

  Be sure to remember that in addition to font families, each variation of italic/non-italic and bold/regular require a separate font symbol!

or

- have not specified the correct font name in your text format

  The name you set in the ActionScript tab of the properties panel for your font symbol refers only to the *class name* it is available under (for use with `Font.registerFont()` in ActionScript).  The font's *display name* (for use with the `font` property of TextFormat, and/or `font-family` in CSS) is set automatically! Each font's display name can be seen in the greyed out text area at the bottom of the "options" tab of your font properties panel in Flash CS5, or you can use [Font.enumerateFonts()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29) to trace all available display names at runtime.

Comment: I haven't actually exported the font for actionscript, should I? I haven't used the actual Font class in my code

Comment: You can't use embedded fonts if you don't embed them ;)

Comment: What I mean is how does the Button class work with the label? how is the font embedded? I don't have to add a Font symbol in the Library.